# Is there a data structure or class in LLDB to store the commands which typed from command line?

Tags: llvm, lldb

For some reasons I need to analysis the commands typed from stdin,eg:"br s -f hello.cpp -l 4". but I find it is hard to get where these commands stored in LLDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lldb command `command history` will dump all the commands typed into the current lldb session.  There isn't an SB API to get at this information in a structured form, but the command output is pretty parseable, and using SBCommandInterpreter.HandleCommand you can programmatically acquire command results.

It looks like `command history` doesn't capture multi-line entry (for instance when entering multi-line `expr` expressions) though that's more of an oversight than a feature.

lldb also populates the editline store with the commands that have been entered.  There are editline API's to get that out, so you might be able to get at that from Python.

Comment: Thanks for your answer！I just solved this problem one minute. the commands typed from the command line are stored in a string "line" in a func which named 
IOHandlerEditline::Run() in IOhandler.cpp.Thank again:)

Comment: If you are trying to watch commands get executed from inside lldb, then you probably want to hook into IOHandlerDelegate::IOHandlerInputComplete for the IOHandler that is managing the command line.  That's the point at which the command is about to be submitted to the LLDB command interpreter.